# Getting a vlaue from a url using regex

Tags: regex, url

how to get the value after the last "|" in the URL query string using regex, any help would be appreciated. 
Example: "xxyzs/SomeStrategy?loc=12000|EXCELOPENXML|2" the targeted value is 2 here.

Comment: What tools are you using? CLI or Programming language? It will be also good for you to provide the EXPECTED result, so we can see what you are aiming at

Comment: Hey, It would be much better for you to provide more details on the language/tools that you are using. This helps the person who is trying to help you be able to help u in a much better way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are using as Programming language, or CLI tools?

But the simplest way to MATCH it is:

```
/.*\|(.*)/
```

as shown here: https://regex101.com/r/eVfNXH/2

Comment: (Re)read the question, they want to match `2` after the last pipe.

Comment: This info was not there initially. Thanks. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `.*\|(.*)` will match everything until the last `|` (greedy search) and capture the rest.

See an [online example](https://regex101.com/r/HHxRVZ/1) with detailed explanation of how this regex accomplishes the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to do to get this to work as you want

1. start at the beginning of the string
2. grab as much of the string as you can
3. work back down the string until you find a `|` character
4. capture what's after the `|` character

as a regex

1. `^` => start at the beginning of the string
2. `.*` => grab as much as you can
3. `\|` => match a `|` character, `|` is special and needs to be escaped
4. `(.*)$` => capture what's left

Put it all together

`/^.*\|(.*)$/`